# Gracefully close Elasticsearch index

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I need to update very simple index setting in the Elasticsearch 5 cluster: `index.query.default_field`. I'm very surprised about the fact, that this setting **is not dynamic** and I need to close the index to update it. It looks strange to me because from Elasticsearch source code it seems like this settings affect only the way incoming requests are processed and doesn't affect data schemas or something else that can be stored on disk or in memory caches.

But the main problem is that after **closing** index and update setting I **reopen** the index and Elasticsearch suddenly start to **re-replicate** all primary shards in this index. It looks very strange because there is no write requests to that index and data stays unchanged for several weeks.

Are there any methods to gracefully **close** an index in such a way to prevent further re-replication when we need to open this index again in future?

Also, are there any reasons for setting `index.query.default_field` to be non-dynamic or this is a mistake?